# Main class of a netbeans project has been deleted

Tags: java, netbeans

Unfortunately I deleted the main class of my netbeans project. Now running my jar file is showing error as "Could not found main class". What should I do? how to rebuild main class. My project Name is "netbeans1" having Source Package that consists "myproject1" as subpackage.myproject1 consists all the form of my project.Should i make the main class for netbeans1 or for myproject1?How to make it? Please help. Your help will be appreciated !!

Comment: So, how did you build it in the first place?

Comment: What stopping you to create another class with same name and adding main method ??

Comment: Btw,is your project is not on cloud (like cvs,svn,git) ????

Comment: A time machine is the only viable fix for your problem.

Comment: Source control, such as Mercurial, Subversion, or Git, works well as a time machine. So do backups. (Greetings @MadProgrammer)

Comment: @andy256 Source control!  Dirty word ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Actually,During making a project,main class is automatically created. I deleted that class. Now my project have "Baseframe" as main class. But running jar file is showing an error message as could not find the main class.

Comment: Ah, okay two things.  1- Does `Baseframe` have a `public static void main(String[] args)` method and 2- Is `BaseFrame` set as the main class in the project properties

Comment: Yes, BaseFrame  set as the main class in the project properties. But it Doesn't have public static void main(String[] args). I got it. Thank You !!

Comment: And 1- You've done a clean and build and 2- Pressing F6 runs the project (using `BaseFrame` as the main class)?

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this,

```
Right click on the folder/directory that the files had been deleted.
Choose Local History – Restore Deleted
Done
```